# Disable mouse click till procedure is done

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Currently I have blocks (3d cubes) , when you click on one , it will create another block on top of it. like so

```
procedure TForm2.cubeClick(sender: TObject);
var
  cube: Tcube;
begin
cube := Sender as Tcube;
if setblocks then
  begin
    totalblocks := totalblocks +1 ;
    CreateCube[totalblocks]:=tcube.Create(self);
    CreateCube[totalblocks].Visible := true;
    CreateCube[totalblocks].Name := 'cubename'+inttostr(totalblocks);
    CreateCube[totalblocks].Position.x := cube.Position.X;
    CreateCube[totalblocks].Position.Y := cube.Position.y;
    CreateCube[totalblocks].Position.Z := cube.Position.Z -1;
    CreateCube[totalblocks].Material.Texture.CreateFromFile(gamedir+'\pics\'+blocktype);
    CubeData[totalblocks] := blocktype;
    CreateCube[totalblocks].Material.Lighting := false;
    CreateCube[totalblocks].Material.Modulation := TTextureMode.tmReplace;
    CreateCube[totalblocks].Parent := viewport3d1;
    CreateCube[totalblocks].OnClick := cubeClick;
    CreateCube[totalblocks].OnMouseDown := mousedown;
  end;
   label2.Text := inttostr(10000 - totalblocks);
end;
```

Issue i am having is if i click fast enough, it stops adding block, unsure why.  but I think if i could disable the mouse click till this whole procedure is done, then it would take care of it. Is this something you can do in firemonkey, anyone know how?

Thanks
Glen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly. First, move your logic out of the `CubeClick` event into another method. (The code below presumes your `Cube` is `Cube1` - adjust it if it isn't.)

```
procedure TForm2.HandleCubeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  cube: Tcube;
  OldCubeClick: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  // Save old handler
  OldCubeClick := Cube1.OnClick;
  // Clear it to disable
  Cube1.OnClick := nil;
  try
    cube := Sender as Tcube;
    if setblocks then
    begin
      totalblocks := totalblocks +1 ;
      CreateCube[totalblocks]:=tcube.Create(self);
      CreateCube[totalblocks].Visible := true;
      // Rest of code here

    end;
  finally
    // Reset handler again to enable
    Cube1.OnClick := OldCubeClick;
  end;
end;
```

Now change your `CubeClick` event to call that new procedure:

```
procedure TForm2.CubeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HandleCubeClick(Sender);
end;
```

Comment: I get error "not enough actual parameters"  on the `cubeClick := nil;` and `CubeClick := OldCubeClick;`  any idea?

Comment: ok, so i am setting the cubs `onclick` to run `CubeClick` and in cube click it tells it to run `HandleCubeClick` which sets `CubeClick` to nil, maybe it should set `onClick` to nil?

Comment: @Glen: My fault. Try the code I posted (note the edits in the first paragraph).

Comment: I had to put the save and clear under the `cube:= sender as Tcube` Cause it could be any cube cube1,cube2..cube400  .   This does work and seems to improve the blocks, as now i can click really fast and when it works it places them correctly.  but still getting issue of every once in awhile the clicking no longer works.  So i am going to accept this as it does answer my question .  Just my question was not fixing my problem as i hoped it would.  thanks

Comment: So weird, it works great as long as i dont click the same spot twice in a row

Comment: Perhaps if you post a new question and clearly explain what the problem is you're having, someone can help you figure it out. You posted some code without context here, and your question was about disabling clicks while one was being handled, which I answered.

Comment: yes your answer was great, never even thought of doing that to disable the mouse click, thanks alot. And yes i added a new question to figure out my little bug.. thanks again

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it makes the onclick , disabled while the procedure is running correct?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ken can you clean this up now? or you not done?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree that the **visible** code does not pump the queue, but there is a lot underlying code not visible to us. The implementation of `TCube`, a number of what appear to be properties or method calls on the class. Any one of these could be calling `Application.ProcesMessages`. What is interesting to note is that Glen observed a specific change in behaviour due to Ken's suggestion (saying now he can click really fast). This strongly implies there is in fact a `ProcessMessages` call somewhere.

Comment: i hope there is a badge for comments...  but really his code helped me , solved half my issue. maybe its not how you would of done it, but i did not see your answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i zipped it up,  just start, create map, put in 20 rows by 20 columns.  it will load map. Click on an image on bottom of map. Now click on any cube . As long as you dont click the same spot twice it works. Also due to the code i added here you can now click as fast as you want , just not same spot twice.  http://www.filesplat.com/~shared-download?id=5S61Z3KGY5OIKSV0POAVDL1YRSJAXPJK

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What about pizza? you care about that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan currently the computer i am on blocks chat here.. But say his code did not make a difference in my code. He code would still disable the onclick event...thus answering the question asked correct?

Comment: @KenWhite dont worry about it, I must say when i get tired of searching for my answer. i come here to read the comments :D  Also you get and extra 100 points due to me adding it to the wrong question :D

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i dont think where close at all..infact i am no closer then i was 2 days ago after adding his code..

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but the this answer was for this question, not my code

Comment: @Dave The question was an indirect question for my code.  at first i did not want to just get the answer. I thought of reasons as to why my code was not working and one was the event was overrideing each other..not sure if could or not, thus i asked the question , how to disable the click.

Comment: that is true, but with out his answer to my question, i would not of learned that.  Cause not knowing that it does not fire, this code assured me it does not. Cause i can see its set to nil

Comment: @Glen - Does this question needs any attention? If not, you can award the bounty so that it doesn't gets any. Otherwise, please try to explain how does the existing answer fails to address to question.

Comment: @davidheffernan where u able to see my issue when u ran the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly disable an `OnClick` event handler. There are a number of ways but the simplest is to set the `OnClick` property to `nil`.

However, doing so will have no impact or bearing on your program. The reason being that the value of the `OnClick` property is never used by the framework during the execution of the `OnClick` event. Input events are not re-entrant. If they were then it would be next to impossible to write UI programs.

In short, your question has a simple answer, but it will not help you solve your problem Setting `OnClick` to `nil` for the duration of your event handler will not change the behaviour of your program.